# Change child element of array item (syntax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a few divs which are using the same class.
Inside the divs are three more divs with identical classes.

```
<div class="plane">
    <div class="win1">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="win2">Dolor sit</div>
    <div class="win3">amet.</div>
</div>

<div class="plane">
    <div class="win1">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="win2">Dolor sit</div>
    <div class="win3">amet.</div>
</div>

var allPlanes = $('.plane');


for (var i = 0; i < allPlanes.length; i++) {

    var onePlane = allPlanes[i];
    var baseHeight = 10;

    $(onePlane + " .win1").css("height", parseInt(baseHeight*1));        
    $(onePlane + " .win2").css("height", parseInt(baseHeight*2));
    $(onePlane + " .win3").css("height", parseInt(baseHeight*3));   

}
```

(Don't mind about the names. It's just an example...)

Now I made an array with the outside divs and I can select the single divs inside. But I did not get the right syntax for the child divs inside.
Can anyone help?

My Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/559xvww6/

Comment: please share the js code.

Comment: You don't need the for loop if you're using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/559xvww6/1/

Comment: @briosheje, your code does not work for me as I have more parameters to keep in mind. e.g. the inside divs have a different height, depending on the parent elements height.

Comment: I didn't get it why it is not working, but it's fine ;) Whatever you mean by "I have more parenthesis to keep in mind" the fiddle above is working and I took your own html as the source!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `+` operator between a `jQuery` object and a string.

The correct way to do it is this:

```
$(".win1", onePlane).css("height", parseInt(baseHeight*1));        
$(".win2", onePlane).css("height", parseInt(baseHeight*2));
$(".win3", onePlane).css("height", parseInt(baseHeight*3));
```

Each of these queries translates to: select all elements with `.winX` that are inside the `jQuery` object `onePlane`.

Comment: I got a lot of correct and helpful answers here, but I have to accept one. So I chose yours as the first given one, that also doesn't change too much on the given code.. Thx!

Comment: I've also choosen this one as the best given answer 'cause I just asked for the right syntax to my given code, not for a complete re-build ;-))

Answer (score 3):

Change you script to this:

```
var allPlanes = $('.plane');

var baseHeight = 10;
$(".plane > .win1").css("height", parseInt(baseHeight*1)+"px");        
$(".plane > .win2").css("height", parseInt(baseHeight*2)+"px");  
$(".plane > .win3").css("height", parseInt(baseHeight*3)+"px");
```

You don't need the for loop in such a case.

A prettier way:

```
var baseHeight = 10;

for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
     $(".plane > .win"+i).css("height", parseInt(baseHeight*i)+"px");          
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/559xvww6/3/

If you don't want to use a for loop and want to dinamically configure from an array:

```
var baseHeight = 10;
$.map([1,2,3], function(i) {
   $(".plane > .win"+i).css("height", parseInt(baseHeight*i)+"px");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/559xvww6/10/

Edit:: Just a side note: all these approachs are valid, but that doesn't mean that they are the best / most efficient ones. Feel free to use the one you like the most, understand it and try to use it or adapt it to your very personal situation. The "easiest" approach is surely the first one, but it is also the longest one.

Comment: Lovely to show more than one way to solve this, thx! 
But: your code does not work out for me as I have more parameters to use in my calculation. E.g. the inside divs have a different height, depending on the parent elements height. So I cannot give all inside elements the same height.

Comment: Then you may just use the first example or provide multiple arrays but, if you have a "complex" case the first solution is the easiest one ;) (and the easiest to customize too)

Comment: The first example would change each and every inside div to the same height all over the page. But I have to make it dependable to the height of the containing ("plane") div.

Answer (score 2):

isn't this one is better:

```js
var base = 10;
$('.plane > div').css('height', function(){
    return base*($(this).index()+1)
});
```

```css
.plane { 
    background-color: #ccc; 
    border: solid 1px #cdcdcd; 
    margin-bottom: 15px; 
}

.plane > .win1 { background-color: #ddd; }
.plane > .win2 { background-color: #eee; }
.plane > .win3 { background-color: #fff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plane">
    <div class="win1">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="win2">Dolor sit</div>
    <div class="win3">amet.</div>
</div>

<div class="plane">
    <div class="win1">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="win2">Dolor sit</div>
    <div class="win3">amet.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use all the same class names inside the nest and then just do `$('.plane:eq(0) .win:eq(2)').html()`

```js
alert( $('.plane:eq(0) .win:eq(2)').html() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plane">
    <div class="win">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="win">Dolor sit</div>
    <div class="win">amet.</div>
</div>

<div class="plane">
    <div class="win">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="win">Dolor sit</div>
    <div class="win">amet.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if your classes are fixed then you can do with this code

```
    $(".win1", $(".plane")).css("height", parseInt(baseHeight*1));        
    $(" .win2", $(".plane")).css("height", parseInt(baseHeight*2));
    $(" .win3", $(".plane")).css("height", parseInt(baseHeight*3));
```

Comment: I have to run through an array of all planes first.. win1 in plane[1] will get another height than win1 in plane[2] if this plane"container" has another height.

Answer (score 1):

You can do using `each` loop of `plane` class.

```
$('.plane').each(function(){
    baseHeight = 10;
    $(this).find(".win1").css("height", parseInt(baseHeight*1));  
    $(this).find(".win2").css("height", parseInt(baseHeight*2));  
    $(this).find(".win3").css("height", parseInt(baseHeight*3));  
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/559xvww6/6/)**

Comment: Does not work for me as the height of the inside divs depends on the planes height. Otherwise I would agree. Thx!

Comment: I just cannot use $('.plane').each() in general. I have to set the height for the inside divs depending on the individual height of the containing ("plane") div.